# Why do I get Seg Faults in my ARM assembly calculator program?

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi3

I am writing calculator program using ARM on Raspian OS; its a simple calculator using reverse polish notation, only using integers and only has 4 operations(add +, sub -, multiply *, MAX M). The code should also run as a continuous loop.

This is my code so far, I can enter the values but I get a seg fault after that.

```
.global main
.func main

main:
    BL _scanf
    MOV R1, R0  

    BL _getchar
    MOV R3, R0

    BL _scanf
    MOV R2, R0

    BL _compare
    B   main

_getchar:
    MOV R7, #3      
    MOV R0, #0              
    MOV R2, #1            
    LDR R1, =read_char      
    SWI 0                
    LDR R0, [R1]           
    AND R0, #0xFF        
    MOV PC, LR            

_scanf:
    PUSH {LR}
    SUB SP, SP, #4          
    LDR R0, =format_str     
    MOV R1, SP             
    BL scanf                
    LDR R0, [SP]            
    ADD SP, SP, #4          
    POP {PC}                 

_compare:
   CMP R3, #'+'            
   BEQ _add     

   CMP R3, #'-'
   BEQ _sub

   CMP R3, #'*'
   BEQ _mul

   CMP R3, #'M'
   BEQ _max

_add:
   MOV R4, LR
   ADD R0, R1, R2
   MOV R0, R0
   BL printf
   MOV PC, R4

_sub:
   MOV R4, LR
   SUB R0, R1, R2
   MOV R0, R0
   BL printf
   MOV PC, R4

_mul:
   MOV R4, LR
   MUL R0, R1, R2
   MOV R0, R0
   BL printf
   MOV PC, R4

_max:
   MOV R4, LR
   CMP R1, R2
   BL printf
   MOV PC, R4


_exit:  
    MOV R7, #1        
    SWI 0  

  .data
  read_char:    .ascii  " "
  format_str:   .asciz  "%d"
```

I apologize in advance for the terrible formatting but it is my first time.
Thank you.

Comment: 1) in _getchar you clobber R1, which is supposed to hold the first operator. 2) shouldn't the strings in .data be `.align 4`-ed?

Comment: Are you able to use a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some very crude code for reference.

- There are no controls to capture bad user input, so you can add code
  for that.
- Numbers are assumed to be < 2^31 - 1, so you can deal with bigger
  values.
- There are you only 3 operators, so you'll need to add additional
  code.
- You'll also need to ensure that there is no stack clobbering.

> .data prompt0: .asciz "Please enter number1: \noperator: (add:
>   +, sub: -, or multiply: *)  \nthen number2: \n" get0: .asciz "%d" get1: .asciz "%s" prompt1: .asciz "%d %c %d = %d\n" .align
>   4 .text .global main .extern scanf, printf, exit main: nop

```
            sub sp, sp, #(4 * 4)

            ldr r0,=prompt0         // prompt user
            bl _print

            ldr r0,=get0            //get number1
            bl _scan
            push {r0}               // save input

            ldr r0,=get1            // get operator
            bl _scan
            push {r0}               // save input

            ldr r0,=get0            // get number2
            bl _scan
            push {r0}               // save input

            pop {r3}                // for printf
            pop {r2}                // for printf
            pop {r1}                // for printf

            cmp r2, #'+'
            beq add
            cmp r2, #'-'
            beq sub
            cmp r2, #'*'
            beq mul

    add:
            add r4, r1, r3
            b output
    sub:
            sub r4, r1, r3
            b output
    mul:
            mul r4, r1, r3

    output:
            ldr r0,=prompt1
            bl _print


            add sp, sp, #(4 * 4)

    _exit:
            b exit

    _print:
            push {r4,lr}            // we only need r4 for the final output; so waste
            bl printf
            pop {r4, pc}

    _scan:
            push {lr}
            sub sp, sp, #4
            mov r1, sp
            bl scanf
            ldr r0, [sp]
            add sp, sp, #4
            pop {pc}
    .end
```

output e.g.:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/asm $ ./calculator_001
Please enter number1: <enter>
operator: (add: +, sub: -, or multiply: *) <enter>
then number2: <enter>
1234
*
6789
1234 * 6789 = 8377626
```